# Печать страницы сразу, без нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, печать

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Второй раз за сегодня.

Есть страница, которую хочется распечатать, без нажатия кнопки печать, и без самой кнопки печать на странице, т.е. открыл ее - вылетает окошко с принтерами, для печати.

Можно ли так сделать на JS ? (и если да, подскажите как)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.onload = print; // что-ли?
```

Comment: я не очень хорошо знаю JS, и изначально смотрел как написать функцию с этим кодом. фантазии хватило только на:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function () {
            window.onload = print;
        }
    </script>

ест-но это не работает

Comment: @mixalef

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = print;
    </script>

Comment: я сейчас покраснел и смеюсь. думал там как то по особенному нужно. спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вставить это в самом конце страницы:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.print();
</script>
```